# C# ASP.NET How to avoid a Session Timeout when webpage content changes a lot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

I have a C# ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio 2012.

I have a Web User Control, which contains a form with about 20 fields. 
Let's call it Person.ascx and has something like:

```
First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
...
```

In the page, I have a dropdown, kind of like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListPersons" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListPersons_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="01" Value="1" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="02" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="03" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    ...
    <asp:ListItem Text="99" Value="99"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And using Jquery UI Accordion, I have the following to show the chosen amount of person forms:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="accordionPersons" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
    <h3 id="accordionPerson_h1" runat="server" >Person 1</h3><div id="accordionPerson_b1" runat="server" ><My:Person ID="Person1" runat="server"></My:Person></div>
    <h3 id="accordionPerson_h2" runat="server" visible="false" >Person 2</h3><div id="accordionPerson_b2" runat="server" visible="false" ><My:Person ID="Person2" runat="server"></My:Person></div>
    <h3 id="accordionPerson_h3" runat="server" visible="false" >Person 3</h3><div id="accordionPerson_b3" runat="server" visible="false" ><My:Person ID="Person3" runat="server"></My:Person></div>
    ..
    <h3 id="accordionPerson_h99" runat="server" visible="false" >Person 99</h3><div id="accordionPerson_b99" runat="server" visible="false" ><My:Person ID="Person99" runat="server"></My:Person></div>
</div>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
protected void DropDownListPersons_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setVisibleControl(Int32.Parse(DropDownListPersons.SelectedValue) >= 1, accordionPerson_h1, accordionPerson_b1);
    setVisibleControl(Int32.Parse(DropDownListPersons.SelectedValue) >= 2, accordionPerson_h2, accordionPerson_b2);
    setVisibleControl(Int32.Parse(DropDownListPersons.SelectedValue) >= 3, accordionPerson_h3, accordionPerson_b3);
    ...
    setVisibleControl(Int32.Parse(DropDownListPersons.SelectedValue) >= 99, accordionPerson_h99, accordionPerson_b99);
}
private void setVisibleControl(bool visible, Control control1, Control control2)
{
    control1.Visible = visible;
    control2.Visible = visible;
}
```

So:

- when I first load the page, it works fine showing one form.
- When I choose a low number (say between 1 and 10), it also works fine.
- But when I choose a big number, say 90, it loads slowly, but works.
- However, after that when I choose a small number (for example 3) I get a session timeout error.

Although it doesn't always happen the first time (sometimes I have to choose 90, then 3 and then 95 for it to fail) it always fails in less the 5 postbacks after loading a big number, even though my session timeout is set for an hour.
This happens with or without an update panel.

Why am I getting a session timeout error when the page content changes too much? 
The delay when choosing a big number is expected, but not the error. How can I avoid this from happening? 
Is there a parameter in IIS or web.config I can change to prevent this from happening? Maybe some memory constraints that causes something to reset automatically?

Comment: What's the session time out value configured in web.config?

Comment: <sessionState timeout="60"/>

Comment: You have 99 user controls each having 20 fields in it in one page. And you post back to page just to make two of them visible and invisible. I would suggest to handle this at client side using JQuery without posting to the server. It will save lot of resources and time of page load for sure.

Comment: You need to rethink your design. Code smell.

Comment: What sort of session timeout error do you see, exactly?